# Why Dart does not allow mixin inheritance?

Tags: dart, mixins, traits

Dart does not support true mixin composition like Scala does.

```dart
library some_lib;

// mixin A
abstract class A {
  String get a => 'A';
}

// mixin B
abstract class B extends Object with A {
  String get b => a + 'B';
}
```

Client usage

```dart
import 'some_lib.dart';

// client usage
class Client extends Object with B {      
  String get c => b + 'C';
}

void main(){
  print(new Client().c); // should print ABC
}
```

Dart analyzer complains saying **"The class 'B' cannot be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than Object"**

I know you would reply that the following works fine:

```dart
class C extends Object with A, B {
  String get c => a + b;
}
```

But I'm designing a library that will export some mixins that share some common functionality (provided by a base mixin), witch is relevant to their behavior, but irrelevant to my library clients.

I would even want to make this base mixin private if possible.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: See https://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/#syntax-and-semantics

Comment: Well, the article states that dart mixin classes must:

1. have no declared constructors.
2. have Object as superclass.
3. contain no super calls.

If you take a look at the code above, class B satisfies these three requirements on syntax and semantics to be a valid mixin.

But I see that [Mixin Composition](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/#mixin-composition) section in the same article states that Dart does not directly support mixin composition.

I think it's yet to be implemented.

If Scala already solved this problem, why couldn't Dart come up with a similar solution?

Comment: any update on this? I am facing the same problem 4 years later :( :(

Comment: now it doesn't work either: 'class C extends Object with A, B'

Answer (score 3):

The specs for this are still evolving. I think they intend to implement full mixin based inheritance in the future releases.

That is what I gleaned from Gilad Bracha's (the brains behind the dart specs) talk here (fast forwarded to the appropriate section): http://youtu.be/yXY5bGlhxlw?t=18m42s